# Is there a guide for using GRSecurity and Precisew/ PAX?

Tags: kernel, security

I'd like to know if there is a guide of some kind for (successfully) configuring, compiling and installing GRSecurity w/PAX etc. in Precise?

I basically am trying to build my own custom release based off of Ubuntu Server and Gnome 2, with the concept of having a distro that is stable, compatible with everything, focused on GPGPU computing, like CUDA, and some security/forensic tools, but with just minimal apps and services needed and nothing more, and of course really secure. I wont go into all of the detail but I insist on it being the way it is, and using Ubuntu Server as the base for many reasons (It's fully encrypted btw too;). I'm not just wanting a GUI for standard server tasks. I wanted to build my own because of the things mentioned above but also I haven't really found a release, other than ~Ubuntu, that has all the tools etc. that I need for the specialized computing requirements I have and I know Ubuntu can definitely do a great job here too!

Everything is great so far but I've run into several snags when trying to install GRsecurity. I've Googled and Googled, read many blogs, sites etc and they either aren't up to date, not that applicable, or there is some kind of issue and error, so that's why I was wondering if there might be something up to date or some kind of help out there for this type of task, or just the best advice someone could offer on hardening it. I went to the #ubuntu IRC chan and they said to ask here, lol.

Any other help or advice regarding anything above would be welcome too.
Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Grsecurity and PaX Configuration Options](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options)

Comment: I did Mitch, many times. Thanks for the response though. I used it over the last couple days for the basis for everything I was trying to do and followed closely. Are there any steps during the install process that are Ubuntu etc. specific and require a certain patch, settings or commands?

Comment: Do not use GRSecurity per the announcement below. Use AppArmor or SeLinux. https://grsecurity.net/announce.php

Comment: @JustinAndrusk Aren't those completely different things? grsecurity protects against kernel vulnerabilities, while AppArmor/SELinux protects against application vulnerabilities.